# Commerce 2 Multi-site Support

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce2

I'm currently working on a multi-market Craft3 project with Commerce2. **Each product can and will have a different fixed price on each page.**

Product A
`project.tld/de-de` - € 120
`project.tld/en-gb` - £ 100

I am aware that Commerce2 has no multi-site support, but I still need a solution for my problem. I tried to modify the LineItem at the event `Order :: EVENT_AFTER_ADD_LINE_ITEM`. But I failed miserably.

Is there perhaps a workaround that could solve the problem?

```
Event::on(Order::class, Order::EVENT_AFTER_ADD_LINE_ITEM, function (Event $e) {
    /** @var Order $order */
    $order = $e->sender;

    foreach ($order->lineItems as $lineItem) {
        $price = '234.0000';
        $lineItem->price = $price;
        $lineItem->salePrice = $price;
        if (is_array($lineItem->snapshot)) {
            $snapshot = $lineItem->snapshot;
        } else {
            $snapshot = json_decode($lineItem->snapshot, true);
        }
        $snapshot['price'] = $price;
        $snapshot['product']['defaultPrice'] = $price;
        $lineItem->snapshot = json_encode($snapshot);
    }
    $order->setLineItems($resultLineItems);
    Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($order);
});
```